# Changing color of a part of an object

Tags: edit-mode, color

I cannot find a way how to change a color to another, say "yellow" of a **quadrangle** on the torus surface.
I'm also interested in the possibility of changing an entire concentric circle of quadrangles around the torus to some other specific color.

Comment: you can select the faces and assign another material or use texture painting.

Comment: hey :) I saw that you are kind of learning Blender at the moment and just as a suggestion my favorite tutorial when I learned Blender was this  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPrnSACiTJ4 in general Blender Guru has great tutorials...

Comment: @moamen Could you please provide me with a more detail how do I assign another material ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are in 'Display material preview mode'

[image]

add new material to the object via '+' button.

[image: add new material to the object via '+' button.]

Go to edit mode. Select the desired faces.

[image]

Select the desired material, click assign.

[image]

Done!

[image]